# Decomposing into 2NF

Tags: database-design, normalization

I'm currently studying normalization. I know how to normalize the data for given unnormalized list.

But I found this question in our past papers. I don't know how to answer to it.

```
Q. Decompose R{a,b,c,d,e,f} into 2NF using following functional dependencies. 

a -> b,c,d,e,f 
b,c -> a,d,e,f 
b -> f 
d -> e
```

Please can anyone tell me how to do this? I went through some earlier questions,
but still have doubts.

For this my answer is:

```
      R0 = a - > b,c
      R1 = b,c - > a,d,e
      R2 = b - > f
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep the simple dependencies as is:

```
b -> f
d -> e
```

Remove the dependent columns from the other dependencies.

```
a -> b,c,d 
b,c -> a,d
```

At this point you have two candidate keys `a` and `b,c`.  As we already have a dependency on `b`.  I would keep the `b,c` dependency and drop the dependency on `a`.  It would appear that `b,c` defines a weak entity (or repeating group) related to `b`.  I would consider creating a unique key on `a`.